# Ubuntu 15.04 Ethernet Problem

Tags: wireless

I just install Ubuntu 15.04 and my WiFi is connected but Internet doesn't work. Mozilla -- Server Not Found.

Comment: Go to Network Menu -> Connection Information. Please post the values of IPv4 Address, Subnet Mask, Default Route and Primary DNS.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is this just on Mozilla Firefox? Try running `ping 8.8.8.8` in a terminal.

If that didn't solve anything, then `sudo lsusb`

Do you see anything mentioning an wireless device?

Also your title mentions ethernet, but you say wireless in your question.